# The Multiple Driver error in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog, i2c, master-slave

I was creating a code for the i2c slave. I am using a counter to change state, however I am encountering the error. The state machine that I was creating is for the single write and single read cycle.

[I2C Protocol Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRFIK.png)

Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable data_counter detected.

```
  2                     input logic i2c_slave_sda_i,     //to the master
  3                     input logic i2c_slave_scl,       //to the master
  4                     input logic i2c_slave_rstn,      //to the master
  5                     output logic i2c_slave_sda_o,   
  6                     output logic i2c_slave_sda_oe,
  7                     output logic i2c_slave_rd_addr,  //to the register file
  8                     output logic i2c_slave_wr_stb,   //to the register file
  9                     output logic i2c_slave_wr_addr,  //to the register file
 10                     output logic i2c_slave_wr_data,  //to the register file
 11                     input logic i2c_slave_read_data);//from the register file 
 12 
 13 logic       start_detect, stop_detect;
 14 logic       start_resetter, stop_resetter;
 15 logic       read_write_bit = 0;                                 //the write or read operation 0=write and 1=read
 16 logic       send_ack;
 17 logic       reset_counter;
 18 logic       data_read_out;
 19 logic       data_write_out;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 20 logic [7:0] data_in;
 21 logic [7:0] data_read;
 22 logic [6:0] regaddr, addr;
 23 logic [6:0] address_counter;                         //used as counter to count the bits of slave address transferred
 24 logic [7:0] data_counter;                            //used as counter to count the bits of data transferred
 25                                                      //as it becomes 0, it enters into the next state
 26 
 27 parameter [6:0] slave_address = 7'b1100000;
 28 
 29 
 30 typedef enum logic [4:0] {IDLE, 
 31                           SLAVE_ADDR,             
 32                           WRITE,
 33                           REGADDR,         
 34                           WRITE_DATA,            
 35                           SLAVE_ADDR_READ,
 36                           READ,            
 37                           READ_DATA} state_t;   
 38 state_t curr_state, next_state;
 39 
 40 
 41 //State Machine//
 42 always_ff @(posedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin 
 43      if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
 44          curr_state <= IDLE;
 45      end
 46      else begin
 47          curr_state <= next_state;
 48      end
 49 end
 50 
 51 always_comb begin
 52   address_counter = 0;                                           //count is zero for preparation of counting the bits of slave address and the data
 53   data_counter = 0;
 54   
 55       case(curr_state)
 56       
 57         IDLE: begin
 58           if (start_detect) begin
 59             next_state = SLAVE_ADDR;                           //if start condition was detected, the state will proceed to matching the slave address
 60           end
 61           else begin 
 62             next_state = IDLE;                           //if start condition was not detected, the SDA remains IDLE
 63         end
 64         end 
 65 
 66         SLAVE_ADDR: begin
 67           if (address_counter == 6) begin     
 68             next_state = WRITE;
 69           end
 70           else begin
 71             next_state = IDLE;                          //if the slave_address don't match, the SDA will return to IDLE
 72           end
 73         end
 74       
 75         WRITE: begin
 76           if (read_write_bit) begin
 77             send_ack = (address_counter == 9) ? 0 : 1;
 78             next_state = REGADDR;                         //if the slave_address match and the operation is write
 79             reset_counter = 0;
 80           end
 81              else begin
 82                 next_state = IDLE;
 83              end
 84         end
 85 
 86         REGADDR: begin
 87           if (data_counter == 7) begin
 88             send_ack = (data_counter == 9) ? 0 : 1;         
 89             next_state = WRITE_DATA;
 90             reset_counter = 0;
 91           end
 92           else begin
 93             next_state = REGADDR;
 94         end
 95         end 
 96 
 97         WRITE_DATA: begin
 98           if(i2c_slave_sda_i == data_in) begin
 99              send_ack = (data_counter == 9) ? 0 : 1;
100              next_state = IDLE;
101            end
102           else if (start_detect) begin
103             next_state = SLAVE_ADDR_READ;
104           end
105          end
106 
107         SLAVE_ADDR_READ: begin
108           if (address_counter == 6) begin
109             send_ack = (address_counter == 9) ? 0 : 1;
110             next_state = READ_DATA;
111             reset_counter = 0;
112           end
113           else begin
114             next_state = IDLE;                          //if the slave_address     don't match, the SDA will return to IDLE
115           end
116         end
117 
118          READ: begin
119            if (!read_write_bit) begin
120              send_ack = (data_counter == 9) ? 0 : 1;  //if the slave_address match     and the operation is read
121              next_state = READ_DATA;                   
122            end
123            else begin
124              next_state = IDLE;
125            end
126          end
127 
128        READ_DATA: begin
129          if (i2c_slave_sda_i == data_read) begin
130             send_ack = (data_counter == 9) ? 0 : 1;
131             next_state = IDLE;
132          end
133          else begin
134             next_state = READ_DATA;
135          end
136        end
137 
138        default: begin
139          next_state = IDLE;
140        end
141      endcase
142 end 
143 
144 //Start Condition
145 always_ff @ (negedge i2c_slave_sda_i) begin
146         if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
147                 start_detect <= 1'b1;
148         end
149 end
150 
151 always_ff @ (negedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin
152         if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
153                 start_resetter <= start_detect;
154         end
155         else begin
156                 start_resetter <= i2c_slave_scl;
157         end
158 end
159 
160 //Stop Condition
161 always_ff @ (posedge i2c_slave_sda_i) begin   
162         if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
163                 stop_detect <= 1'b1;
164         end
165 end
166 
167 
168 //Matching of the slave address
169 always_ff @(posedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin
170   if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
171      address_counter <= '0;                                               //count is zero for preparation of counting the bits of slave address
172   end
173   else if (address_counter == 0) begin
174      addr[address_counter] <= i2c_slave_sda_i;
175      address_counter <= address_counter + 1;
176    end
177 end
178 
179 //Storing the register address
180 always_ff @(posedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin
181   if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
182        data_counter <= '0;
183   end
184      else if (data_counter == 0) begin
185        regaddr[data_counter] <= i2c_slave_sda_i;
186        data_counter <= data_counter + 1;
187      end
188 end
189 
190 //Storing the Data byte at write cycle
191 always_ff @(posedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin
192 if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
193         data_in <= 8'b00000000;                                                     
194     end
195     else begin
196         data_in [7] <= i2c_slave_sda_i;
197         data_in [6] <= data_in [7]; 
198         data_in [5] <= data_in [6];
199         data_in [4] <= data_in [5];
200         data_in [3] <= data_in [4];
201         data_in [2] <= data_in [3];
202         data_in [1] <= data_in [2];
203         data_in [0] <= data_in [1]; 
204     end
205 end
206 
207 //Storing the data byte at read cycle
208 always_ff @(posedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin
209 if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
210         data_read <= 8'b00000000;                                                     
211     end
212     else begin
213         data_read [7] <= i2c_slave_sda_i;
214         data_read [6] <= data_read [7]; 
215         data_read [5] <= data_read [6];
216         data_read [4] <= data_read [5];
217         data_read [3] <= data_read [4];
218         data_read [2] <= data_read [3];
219         data_read [1] <= data_read [2];
220         data_read [0] <= data_read [1]; 
221     end
222 end
223 
224 endmodule
```

The error is in these lines:

/i2c_slave.sv,169|8): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable address_counter detected.

/i2c_slave.sv,180|8): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable data_counter detected.

Comment: Recommend removing line numbers so that others can compile code without removing them. If you need to referrer to a particular line use a comment and say // this is line 169.

Answer (score 0):

Variable(s) address_counter and data_counter are driven around line 51:

```
always_comb begin
  address_counter = 0;
  data_counter    = 0;
```

Here is a 2nd driver of address_counter:

```
//Matching of the slave address
always_ff @(posedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin
  if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
    address_counter <= '0;  //count is 0 4 of counting the bits of slave address
  end
  else if (address_counter == 0) begin
    addr[address_counter] <= i2c_slave_sda_i;
  address_counter <= address_counter + 1;
  end
end
```

Here is a 2nd driver of data_counter:

```
//Storing the register address
always_ff @(posedge i2c_slave_scl or negedge i2c_slave_rstn) begin
  if (!i2c_slave_rstn) begin
       data_counter <= '0;
  end
     else if (data_counter == 0) begin
       regaddr[data_counter] <= i2c_slave_sda_i;
       data_counter <= data_counter + 1;
     end
end
```

There are two variables in the posted code which have multiple drives as the tool is indicating.

In Verilog/SV RTL synthesis workflows, the designer is modeling hardware.
When inferring multiple drivers the posted code is asking the tool to connect the outputs of two driving sources together, which is generally not possible in Verilog.
From a hardware engineering point of view, its like connecting the output of two CMOS logic gates together.
There are exceptions, however those exceptions don't apply to the posted code.

For more on multiple drivers see
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/497349/is-it-possible-to-have-a-register-with-multiple-drivers

There is at least one other serious issue with the code.  Variable addr is declared this way

```
logic [6:0] addr;
```

which is a single vector; its not a memory/array.
However the post refers to it as a memory/array (multiple vectors).

```
addr[address_counter] <= i2c_slave_sda_i;
```

If you want to use a memory/array, then declare the variable as a memory/array with both packed (vector) and unpacked (array) dimensions.

```
// a 255 location memory of 7-bit vectors
logic [6:0] addr [7:0];
```

The same issue exists with variable regaddr.